# how do you detect if your website visitor came from a google search result?

Tags: php, html

when a user searches from google and lands on our site from the results he/she was shown in the results page, is there a way for my site to detect that he came from google?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable which should contain the referring URL. Please note that this is not tamper-proof or fail-safe as the `Http-Referer` header can easily been changed or modified by a client.

**EDIT:**
Just googled for `phpinfo` (because chanes were high that I get a `phpinfo()` page that shows the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable) to show you how the `Http-Referer` will look like:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] = "http://www.google.de/search?hl=de&q=phpinfo&btnG=Google-Suche&meta="
```

As you see, you can also extract the search term used in the google query (or detect if the search was initiated by the Google Chrome address bar)...

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you can use the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] variable.  But I think the value is controlled by the client and can't always be guaranteed to exist or accurate.

Answer (score 2):

You would check the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` if you wanted to do it in PHP. You can also  use `document.referrer` in javascript.

Comment: Shouldn't this be 'HTTP_REFERER'?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the HTTP_ REFERER var in the $_SERVER array:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

This shoudl then include something like http://www.google.com/?q=etc

Note however that the REFERER is not always set because clients can disable their browser to send it in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Check referrer of a request. It should contain www.google.com/...

Answer (score 0):

HTTP_REFERER : Returns a string containing the URL of the page that referred the request to the current page using an  tag. If the page is redirected, HTTP_REFERER is empty.

Using HTTP_REFERER used for ASP.