# PHP-Visitor from google

Tags: php

How can I find with p h p if someone comes to my website from google?

```
<?php
  if (isset($_COOKIE['source'])) {
      $arr = explode("=",$_COOKIE['source']);
      $_SESSION['source'] = $arr[1];
      unset($_COOKIE['source']);
  }
?>
```

This is how I get the source, to know where was the visitor before my site and I want to set `$_SESSION['source']="google"` if he was searching on Google to find my page.

Comment: Use `session_start();` on top of your code.

Comment: The keyword is **referer**. Ironically, Google should help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700672/how-do-you-detect-if-your-website-visitor-came-from-a-google-search-result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: [$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']](http://php.net/manual/bg/reserved.variables.server.php)

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'google'))
echo 'comes from google';
```

Comment: How can I test this on a local server?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. This global variable should contain the referer url.

Comment: I think the newer problem is Google using HTTPS, which means the referer will not be sent. At least I recognize this in my Piwik Analytics tool and google results said that since google uses HTTPS for their search engine, the keywords (which would belong to the referer) are not submitted to the target website anymore.

Comment: Ah, [according to Google](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=173733) only the search terms are not part of the referer anymore. So it would at least be possible to determine if somebody came via Google.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. It parses the given URL if there is any and then removes all unneeded information like [Top-Level-Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLD) or third- or lower level domains, so we only have the second level domain remaining (**google**).

```
function isRequestFromGoogle() {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
        $host = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST);
        if (!$host) {
            return false; // no host found
        }

        // remove the TLD, like .com, .de etc.
        $hostWithoutTld = mb_substr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 0, mb_strrpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], '.'));
        // get only the second level domain name
        // e.g. from news.google.de we already removed .de and now we remove news.
        $domainName = mb_substr($hostWithoutTld, mb_strrpos($hostWithoutTld, '.') + 1);

        if (mb_strtolower($domainName) == 'google') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for users that are comeing from adwords, but google sends no parameters and my $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is empty so I can't tell if they were searching on google or they have entered directly on my page.

Comment: I think you cannot do anything if the referer is empty. That’s possible and I think it’s the only resource for the prior URL the person has visited (despite some Javascript hacks, where you could see the browser history, that were possible for some time in some buggy browsers, but should be impossible now).